# Alternative Intellisense Tooltip?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, intellisense

Is there an alternative to Visual Studio's intellisense tooltip when typing parameter info? If not, is it easy to implement my own?

The reason being is that at my work we use a framework with long namespaces, so when working with a function, the parameters are listened next to each other in the parameter info tooltip, and it becomes very long across my screen. I would like to have a tooltip that displays each parameter on its own line in the tooltip.

Comment: Use Jetbrains' Resharper.

Comment: I just checked their website. They also display their parameter info horizontally :/ but thanks! :)